# ruby, two ways how to pass params to proc

Tags: ruby

I looked through this [code](http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-ruby-1272.html) and found author passes params to block using []. I tryed it myself

```
my_proc = proc { |x| x + 1 }
a = 0
my_proc[a]        # => 1
my_proc.call(a)   # => 1
```

What is the difference between this two calls? Is this a syntax sugar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways are exactly the same and are aliases to each other. Thus, both variants call the same method which is not determined by any special syntax. It is basically defined as:

```
class Proc
  def call(*args)
    #...
  end

  alias [] call
end
```

You might be interested to note that there is even a third way:

```
my_proc.(a)
```

This is actually syntactic sugar (i.e. is an extension of the syntax of the Ruby language language). All objects accepting `#call` can be "called" that way and Ruby ensures to invoke the `call` method.

Comment: This definition `alias [] call` makes everything clear. Thanks.

Comment: ...and a fourth: [Proc#yield](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-yield).  If it has one argument, a fifth: [Proc#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D).

Answer (score 1):

They are functionally identical. You can use whichever style you prefer.